# Build an Affordable Linux Tablet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, devices, tablet

I have 3 young children and my wife has asked that the girls get a tablet, for basic gaming, and online web tutorials (school work usually).

Has anyone created or built a good affordable Linux tablet? Could anyone provide advice on good cheaper hardware that I could use to build their tablets.

What OS would I use to create the tablet Fedora, Ubuntu or Meego https://meego.com/ ?

Looking for ideas on how best to go about achieving the project, any ideas welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack exchange. This is a [questions and answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/about) site. Shopping advice does not work well here, please read [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Besides, you can't afford to build one tablet, these things have to be mass-produced. Any tablet you buy will have an OS already.

Comment: @Gillies I don't agree with the thread being unconstructive. Its unique and something that no other thread directly answered.                    If a person can't afford an Ippad or an Ipad is not appropriate cost for the age of the children then bulding a good tablet for your children would be a good project. I am sure others would have acheived this and would like there input. Which specific words need changing so I can get this valuable topic restarted?

Comment: For others who comes searching here is the links to fedora and opensuse arm. http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM   http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:ARM

Comment: For the second and last time: buying an already-made tablet will cost you a lot less than building your own, because it's mass produced and you can't buy the parts individually anyway. An iPad is about the most expensive you'll find; cheaper tablets usually run Android.

Comment: For the cheapest hardware, you could try China (like dx.com). The hw will be very low-spec and even suspicious and the software outdated.

Comment: @gilels most tablets will have an OS, but most likely Android, which sucks in many aspects. Plus it's often not easy to find out what hw is actually inside. And we can't forget issues with graphics drivers.

Comment: @peterph. My question was closed as unreasonable last year but now it's all the rage . Everyone is putting Linux on Nexus 7, Chromebooks and crap Android OS devices. What difference a year makes. It wouldn't be closed this year.

Comment: @sayth I think it's still is a valid question (though not for this site) - having an open-specification tabled, i.e. open bootloader and hw specs, possibly with documented hardware would be spectacular.

Comment: One of you lazy oafs could have at least made a positive contribution and try to post a decent answer if the question is closed. Shame on you at all. Nobody likes to talk about Q&A site groundrules.